# Is there any event on which we can observe eav attribute option save

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, eav-attributes

I tried `eav_entity_attribute_save_after` but its not working.

Which event triggerd during eav attrbiute save can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Not working with `before` also i m working with M2.2

Comment: try this one `eav_collection_abstract_load_before`

Comment: Not working `eav_collection_abstract_load_before`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this event it's working for me.

Event name :: `adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_frontend_prepare_form`

In observer you can get attribute detail and option like below

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $attributeData = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute()->getData(); /* for attribut data */
$optionData = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute()->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        echo '<pre>';print_r(attributeData);exit();
        echo '<pre>';print_r($optionData);exit();
        return $this;
    }
```